# Apache 2.4 on Windows - Include folder out of DocumentRoot

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I need to include a folder on my **httpd.conf** that is out of my `DocumentRoot` directory. I know there is a lot of info about this but not specifically for **Apache 2.4** running on **Windows**. I tried a lot of things but anything works, I always get a forbidden error, and this is driving me mad.

Here is my default config made by WAMP:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

That's OK but I need to include a folder project on my E:\ disk.
I have tried all of these, obviously restarting the apache server after every attempt:

*Attempt #1*

```
<Directory "e:/Development/[Git]/projectName/public/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*Attempt #2*

```
<Directory "e:/Development/[Git]/projectName/public/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

*Attempt #3*

```
Alias /projectName "e:/Development/[Git]/projectName/public/"
# The <Directory> on attempts #1 and #2
```

**Just to clarify:**

I have tried a lot of combinations using `/` or `\`. Also using `"` or without. I even tried to escape the `[]` like this `\[Git\]`.

I already have a `VirtualHost` well configured for that directory. I know it because if I remove the security on the `<Directory />` then works fine, but as I have read this is a lack of security that I do not want to have:

```
# Disabling the security as below is not an option
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance